# Remind Vs. recall in context

Tags: word-choice

My friend asked me today "How's your project going?" But I didn't really remember on what project he's talking about. What would work better as an answer in this context, "Remind me" or "recall me"?

Comment: *remind* someone, *recall* something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Remind** me" is good.

"**Recall**" has a different meaning. It describes the activity that goes on within your mind when you call something up from your own memory. So "**Recall** me" wouldn't be appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

You recall what was forgotten.

You remind a person who has forgotten something.

> I recalled his phone number.
>
> I reminded her that she had an appointment.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that to use "recall", it has to be: "help/make me recall". "To remind" has the meaning "to make remember" or "to make recall".